# What is a Monolithic Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Monolithic Word™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Monolithic Words™ | Not Monolithic Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ALCHEMY | ACCUSE |
| BURNING | BIZARRE |
| CUIRASS | DUSTY |
| EXPIRY | EXCUSE |
| HOCUS | HIDEOUS |
| JIGGLE | ILLEGAL |
| OXIDE | STARK |
| VICTORY | WINCE |
| ZODIAC | ZIGZAG |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Monolithic Words™,Not Monolithic Words™
ALCHEMY,ACCUSE
BURNING,BIZARRE
CUIRASS,DUSTY
EXPIRY,EXCUSE
HOCUS,HIDEOUS
JIGGLE,ILLEGAL
OXIDE,STARK
VICTORY,WINCE
ZODIAC,ZIGZAG
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Monolithic Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Monolithic Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Hint 1:

> What is the main property of a monolith?

Hint 2:

> The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is not really 42, it's $\textbf{*}$ as the wildcard symbolizes everything... and possibly some other reason too ;)

Hint 3: (an extension of Hint 2)

> What is the relation between $\textbf*$ and 42?

Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess:

> A monolithic word is a word that, when turning every (upper case) letter into [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and concatenate them, it becomes a prime.
>  eg ALCHEMY. A->$65$, L->$76$ etc. So ALCHEMY -> $65766772697789$ is a prime.
>  eg ACCUSE -> $656767858369=7\times 7\times 239\times 56081279$ is not a prime.
>  The last hint is a big giveaway: the ASCII code for $*$ is $42$ :)

Comment: @r_64 Good job! :) I think I made this harder than required. :)

Answer (score 2):

---

**First attempt (wrong):**

My first guess (but based on the example is wrong ) is that a Monolithic Word...

> ...does not contain other words (as a monolith is a single piece element), but this is not the case for **BURN**ING or CUIR**ASS**
>
>    For the Non-Monolithic words
>
>   -  ACC**USE**
>
>   -  **BIZ**ARRE
>
>   -  **DUST**Y
>
>   -  EXC**USE**
>
>   -  **HIDE**OUS
>
>   -  IL**LEGAL**
>
>   -  **STAR**K
>
>   -  **WIN**CE
>
>   -  **ZIG**ZAG

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the correct path :(  Nice spotting though, and strange that it is accurate to this degree even though I didn't intend it :)

Comment: Also, jiggle contains jig and oxide contains ox.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... I will try another approach then

Comment: Moreover, 'victory' contains 'victor'

Comment: I noticed this, with three-letter words only. USE, BIZ<sub>questionable</sub>, STY, USE, HID, ILL, TAR, WIN, ZIG<sub>questionable</sub>. Problem is, you end up with HEM, URN, ASS, and JIG on the wrong side.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be wrong but

> A monolith is a monument carved out of a single stone .
>
>  The Monolithic Words ™ can be derived by starting with a single letter.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "derived"? :)

Comment: So you start with one letter, then add another to form a meaningful word. This goes on and on till you get the target word.

Comment: Sorry, but not the correct path :( I'm adding the next hint now, good luck with the puzzle! :D